# Multi threading two threads reach same point

Tags: multithreading

You have two threads one runs function f1() and the other runs f2().
Sometimes f1 has never finished despite that all prints of f2 is seen.
Explain how can that happen and give a solution?

```
int _f2_finished = 0;

Void f1()
{
    print(“f1 waiting “);
    while (!_f2_finished) {usleep(50);}
    print(“share of work”);
}

void f2()
{
   Printf(“f2 doing some stuff”);
   usleep(5*1000*1000);
   Printf(“f2 signaling finished”);
   _f2_finished = 1;
   Printf(“f2 signaled finished”);
}
```

I tried to solve it I couldn't understand how come f1() stays stuck in the while loop despite that all the messages of f2 printed meaning _f2_finished is 1 which quits the while loop?

It is C language and windows platform.

Comment: What threading library or threading model are you using? What does it say about accessing an object in one thread while another thread is, or might be, modifying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most threading models specify that it is illegal to access an object in one thread while another thread is, or might be, modifying it. They do provide ways to legally share data, such as atomic operations, mutexes, and so on.

As it happens, in this particular case, you need a "memory visibility" guarantee. That is, something that ensures that a change made in one thread is seen "soon" in another thread. Guaranteeing memory visibility requires many compiler optimizations (such as caching a variable's value in a register) to be disabled, so you only get it when you ask for it.

On Windows, you have a lot of choices. You can use a CRITICAL_SECTION to protect the shared value or you can use the various `Interlocked` operations.

On all known Windows platforms, using `volatile` to provide memory visibility in cases where atomicity is not needed happens to work and it's very unlikely that this will change in the near future. If you don't understand that, ignore it and just use something that's easy to get right and hard to get wrong like a mutex. (Because if you use `volatile` this way without a deep understanding, sooner or later you'll use it in a case where it happens not to work reliably and your code will fail in the worst way at the worst time.)

Comment: I still don't understand why it is illegal to access an object while other thread modifying it sooner or later the value will be updated and f1 will exit the while loop

Comment: @Nizarazo It's illegal because that's what the rules say. There's no guarantee that "sooner or later the value will be updated" because there is no such thing as "*the* value". There is no "one true value" because the rules don't require there to be. The rules just require that if your program follows the rules it works correctly. They don't require the compiler to figure out how to make programs that break the rules work.

Comment: In your case, the `while` loop probably only reads `_f2_finished` once. Since the rules say you can't modify it in another thread, the compiler is free to assume its value can't change. This makes code that follows the rules more efficient. The compiler is not required to figure out how to keep your naive assumptions valid, and it likely doesn't.

Comment: And there's an extremely valuable less here. *Never*, ever ever conclude that code is safe and reliable just because you can't think of a way it can fail. Nobody is clever enough to think of all the ways non-trivial code can fail. You need a *guarantee* that the code is valid.

Comment: Do you mean in windows there is a rule like this: "Since the rules say you can't modify it in another thread" ?

Comment: Why the while loop reads _f2_finsihed only once ? I am not understanding?

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows is not as well documented as, for example, POSIX pthreads are. But like pretty much all threading models, you only get a memory visibility guarantee when you use something that specifically provides it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96599/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-nizarazo).